# how exclude current post and unwanted taxonomy from custom post type query

Tags: php, wordpress, taxonomy, custom-taxonomy, taxonomy-terms

I'm in single-product.php that I create a custom post type before and also create a taxonomy called product-cat. one of the taxonomy that I used in other query is "new-and-best-seller".

At single-product.php In a section I want to query related product except current product and "new-and-best-seller" taxonomy.

Notice that some of the products have multiple taxonomy involving "new-and-best-seller" that I can't use AND relation because it exclude other product that have related categories (I comment that codes).

This is my code so far:

```
    <?php $productCats = get_the_terms($post->ID, 'product-cat');
//Pluck to get an array of ids
$productCats_ids = wp_list_pluck($productCats, 'term_id');
?>
<?php
$relatedProducts = new WP_Query(array(
  'post_type' => 'product',
  'tax_query' => array(
    // 'relation' => 'AND',
    array(
      'taxonomy' => 'product-cat',
      'field' => 'id',
      'terms' => $productCats_ids,
      'operator' => 'IN',
    ),
    // array(
    //   'taxonomy' => 'product-cat',
    //   'field' => 'id',
    //   'terms' => array('new-and-best-seller'),
    //   'operator' => 'NOT EXISTS'
    // )
  ),
  'category__not_in' => array(28)
));
if ($relatedProducts->have_posts()) { ?>
  <section id="newest-products" class="mb-section">
    <div class="container">
      <h1 class="main__title">
        <strong class="main__title--bold">Related products</strong>
      </h1>
      <div class="newest-products-wrapper owl-carousel owl-theme">
        <?php while ($relatedProducts->have_posts()) {
          $relatedProducts->the_post(); ?>
          <div class="card product-card">
            <img class="card-img-top product-card--img" src="./assets/images/image 401.jpg" alt="">
            <?php the_post_thumbnail('medium', array('class' => 'card-img-top product-card--img')); ?>
            <div class="card-body">
              <h2 class="card-title product-card--title"><?php esc_html(the_title()); ?></h2>
              <a href="<?php esc_url(the_permalink()); ?>" class="product-card--more">See available items</a>
            </div>
          </div>
        <?php }
        wp_reset_postdata(); ?>
      </div>
    </div>
  </section>
<?php } ?>
```

Comment: Can you please clarify _"because it exclude other product that have related categories"_? I can't tell from your description what exactly the issue is supposed to be. A specific example of what posts exists with what taxonomy terms, and which ones of those you do want to get, and which ones you don't, might help.

Comment: thanks for your reply. I mean for example: I'm in one of the "A" taxonomy product and we have also "B" and "new-and-best-seller" tax for other products.
some products have "A" and "new-and-best-seller" some have just "A" and some product have "A" and "new-and-best-seller" and maybe some product have just "new-and-best-seller" tax. the query should exclude "new-and-best-seller" products but not the "A" tax products from finding realted product. and query should exclude the prodcut that user is in the page of. Briefly just find "A" taxonomy product without current page product.

Comment: and of course maybe a product have "A" , "B" tax. it sould handle all of possible condition dynamically. thanks

Comment: Sorry, but I still can't tell what exactly you want. But anyway - no one is forcing you to have just _one_ `X AND Y` condition in your query, you can also do `(X AND Y) OR (Foo AND Bar)`, you just need to nest it properly. Also, I am not sure what exactly the difference between operators `NOT EXISTS` and `NOT IN` is when it comes to taxonomy queries, so maybe try the other one.

Comment: Thats odd if you don't understand what I'm saying. maybe more explain should works:
I am on a single product that have an taxonomy  "A" and "new-and-best-seller"
how can I exclude "new-and-best-seller" and the single product that I'm in the page now and show the rest of "A" taxonomy products? Can't explain in Other way!!! ;)

Comment: I would assume that `IN` A and `NOT IN` new-and-best-seller should get you all the relevant products; and to exclude the current product, use `post__not_in`, https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/classes/wp_query/#post-page-parameters

Comment: if you mean something like that. it dosen't work
'tax_query' => array(
        'relation' => 'AND',
        array(
          'taxonomy' => 'product-cat',
          'field' => 'id',
          'terms' => $productCats_ids,
          'operator' => 'IN',
        ),
        array(
          'taxonomy' => 'product-cat',
          'field' => 'id',
          'terms' => array('new-and-best-seller'),
          'operator' => 'NOT IN'
        )
      ),

but post__not_in works for exclude current product

Comment: `'field' => 'id', 'terms' => array('new-and-best-seller')`- that doesn't match. The _id_ of your term is not `new-and-best-seller`. You need to set field to either `slug` or `name` (with the dashes in there, I would assume this is the former.)

Comment: Thats right. I use slug in field before and now changing to id but don't change the terms

Comment: However this way of excluding, excludes products that have "A" and "new-and-best-seller". I think this way is not true. I should exclude "new-and-best-seller" from 
get_the_terms(). have any idea of how?

Comment: get_the_terms has no options for that, so you will have to remove it from the returned array yourself, before you pass it on to wp_list_pluck.

Comment: I found 'cat' => '-28' exclude in general category but for custom taxonomy I found none.
anyone know how to do this?

Answer (score 1):

The pseudo-code below is presented to clarify the question.

### Pseudo-code

```
$post1 = has( 'term' => array( 'new-and-best-seller' , 'A' ) );

$post2 = has( 'term' => array( 'new-and-best-seller', 'B' ) );

$post3 = has( 'term' => array( 'B', 'A', 'new-and-best-seller' ) );

$post4 = has( 'term' => array( 'new-and-best-seller' ) );

$post5 = has( 'term' => array( 'A' ) );
```

The five posts above are from your custom post type and indicate the **product-cat** taxonomy terms they have. **$post1** is the current post.

The question is: "how do I filter my custom posts to include **$post3** and **$post5** (posts related to **$post1** via taxonomy term **A**) while excluding **$post2**, **$post4** and the current post (**$post1**)?

The query below should find the desired posts. (*The code below does not include the WP_Query variable `category__not_in`. It was not clear how it relates to your question. So, you might need to include it.*)

### Solution

```
function filter_for_product_custom_post() {
$unwanted_term_slug = 'new-and-best-seller';
$custom_taxonomy    = 'product-cat';

$current_post_id = \get_the_ID();

$unwanted_term_ids = \get_terms(array(
  'taxonomy' => $custom_taxonomy,
  'slug'     => $unwanted_term_slug,
  'fields'   => 'ids'
));

$wanted_term_ids = \wp_get_object_terms(
  $current_post_id,
  $custom_taxonomy,
  array(
    'exclude' => $unwanted_term_ids,
    'fields'  => 'ids'
  )
);
?>
<?php
$relatedProducts = new WP_Query(array(
  'post_type' => 'product',
  'tax_query' => array(
    array(
      'taxonomy' => $custom_taxonomy,
      'field' => 'term_id',
      'terms' => $wanted_term_ids,
      'operator' => 'IN',
    ),
  ),
  'post__not_in' => array($post->ID), //exclude current product
));

    ...

    while ( $relatedProducts->have_posts() ) {
        $relatedProducts->the_post();

        ...

    }

    ...

    \wp_reset_postdata();

}
```

Comment: Hi, and thanks for your notice. you misunderstood what I'm asking. I clarify my question with your Pseudo-code:
$post1 = has('term' => array( 'new-and-best-seller' , 'A' ));

$post2 = has('term' => array( 'new-and-best-seller', 'B' ));

$post3 = has( 'term' => array( 'B', 'A', 'new-and-best-seller' ) );

$post4 = has( 'term' => array('new-and-best-seller' ) );

$post5 = has( 'term' => array('A' ));
now if user are in $post1 page, related posts should be: $post3, $post5

Comment: @Alipvd I updated my answer with your examples. The query did not change from my original answer because the clause that looks for posts without the unwanted term would eliminate posts with `new-and-best-seller`. In the original answer `$wanted_term_ids` could include the unwanted term `new-and-best-seller`. The updated answer now excludes `new-and-best-seller` from `$wanted_term_ids`. Please indicate if this works. Thanks.

Comment: Unfortunately your updated code didn't change anything. not exclude "new-and-best-seller" tax from query products. I think exclude a tax must be before query products

Comment: @Alipvd Could you please be more specific about which case is included in the results that should not be there? Are you saying example **$post2** or **$post4** or both types are still showing up? Also, I noted that `category__not_in` is not in my solution. Could the problem be related to `category__not_in`? Because your question included a category_id without explaining what it is, it is not clear if it is related to the problem.

Comment: @Alipvd I found the problem. `'exclude' => array( $unwanted_term_ids ),` was not excluding the unwanted term as expected when assigning the value to `$wanted_term_ids`. It has to be changed to `'exclude' => $unwanted_term_ids[0],`. The [WordPress documentation for WP_Term_Query](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/classes/wp_term_query/__construct/) shows that arrays of integers should work; but, it doesn't for some reason. I updated my answer with the change. Please test again, and let me know if it works.

Comment: Thanks. IT WORKS. the way that you get the unwanted tax and exclude it in $wanted_term_ids is just what I wanted.
Just A little thing in WP_Query don't need that nested arraies and relation $wanted_term_ids get us the current product taxonomy without "new-and-best-seller"
and just a simple tax_query like this make things works just fine:
      'tax_query' => array(
        array(
          'taxonomy' => $custom_taxonomy,
          'field' => 'id',
          'terms' => $wanted_term_ids,
          'operator' => 'IN',
        ),
      )

Comment: and of course  don't need $unwanted_term_ids[0] just $unwanted_term_ids make this thing works. thank you again

Comment: @Alipvd I accepted your changes except for the `field` option in `tax_query`. The WordPress documentation for [tax_query](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/classes/wp_query/#taxonomy-parameters) does not list `id` as a value (even though it might work). You can mark the answer as accepted now if everything is ok. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

This is not asking my question its just for clarify my question more because stackoverflow don't allow to write this in comment dear kofeigen.

Hi, and thanks for your notice. you misunderstood what I'm asking. I clarify my question with your Pseudo-code:

```html
$post1 = has('term' => array( 'new-and-best-seller' , 'A' ));

$post2 = has('term' => array( 'new-and-best-seller', 'B' ));

$post3 = has( 'term' => array( 'B', 'A', 'new-and-best-seller' ) );

$post4 = has( 'term' => array('new-and-best-seller' ) );

$post5 = has( 'term' => array('A' ));
```

now if user are in $post1 page, related posts should be: $post3, $post5